# MySQL: Dynamically creating outfile from table and storing on client machine

Tags: c#, mysql

I am a C# programmer, and would like to create an outfile of data on a certain table on my Windows PC.

In my C# script I called this function

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand($"Select * from EC_ExtraResources into outfile '{DownloadPath}/{DateTime.Now}.csv' fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"' lines terminated by '\n'", connection);
adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, I got the error "Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/D:/.../Extra Resources' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)"  (D:/.../Extra Resources represents intermediate folders)

After looking up online, I learnt that "Select … Into Outfile" stores the table data into a server file rather than on my PC. Given that there is no "Select … Info Outfile Local" unlike "Load Data Local …", what should I do to get the table data info a file on my PC?

I have seen similar questions that talk about accessing the directory '/var/lib/files' but I do not know where to access this. Is this a server location or a location on my PC?

On another note, an alternative to using Select into outfile, would be to Select * from table and parse the data in my C# code. However, the data in the table is very large and I keep receiving timeout errors despite having set most system timeout variables to 28800 seconds. Why is this the case?

P.S.: I am a 15-yo hobbyist programmer and am not experienced with MySQL, so I'm sorry if my question is basic and I am missing out on a simple solution. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: '/var/lib/files' is a folder name yes. It's the style of path name you get on Mac or Linux computers. If you save the file there you may not be able to access it. Depends if you have a login to the server itself (rather than just mysql)? Another question, if there are so many rows that it times out when querying....why do you want to export this amount of data, what's the purpose of doing so?

Comment: If the table is large, then page through using limit clause.

Comment: @ADyson the data contains 34 images, each about 3.5MB. In the app I'm creating, a user can have the option to download extra resources for an enhanced experience.

Comment: @Shadow thanks for the idea. If I can't find a solution for using outfile soon, then I'll use your idea and mark it as an answer.

Comment: Outfile does not support the local parameter.

Comment: OK I've got it to work, thanks for the help :)
@Shadow you might want to create an answer and i'll mark it as solution

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution found by paging through the table using limit clause